# Symplifying Inequality involving Binomials

Tags: inequality

Is there any easy way of simplifying the following inequality

$$ (a+\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma} -  (b-\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma} > a^{\gamma} - b^{\gamma} $$

if $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $a>b>\Delta$.

Another option might be trying to find a bound for how large this difference can be.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that $a>b>\Delta$

Comment: Yes, edited. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to prove that it is true, what do you mean by simplify?

Comment: I want to cancel things as much as possible. For example, if $\gamma=2$ then the inequality reduces to $(a+b)\Delta>0$

Answer (score 1):

Write the question as follows, and obtain the consequent equivalent formulations:
$$
(a+\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma} -  a^{\gamma} >  (b-\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma}- b^{\gamma}\\
 \int_0^\Delta \frac{\gamma}{2}(a+\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1} \, dt>  - \int_0^\Delta \frac{\gamma}{2}(b-\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1} \, dt\\
\frac{\gamma}{2} \int_0^\Delta (a+\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1} + (b-\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1}  \, dt>  0
$$
Now since the integrand is positive, this proves the claim.$\qquad \Box$

Comment: Thanks for the very correct answer. However, I am not as interested in proving the statement. I am more interested into bounding it or simplifying it.
Is there any easy bound (which can depend on $\delta,a$ and $b$ on this integral?

Comment: Very rough, you could argue: for $\gamma >1$, $(a+\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1} + (b-\frac{t}{2})^{\gamma-1} > a^{\gamma-1} + (b-\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma-1} $, so the LHS is bounded by $\frac{\gamma \Delta}{2} [a^{\gamma-1} + (b-\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma-1} ]$. For $\gamma \le 1$, with the same reasoning you have the lower bound $\frac{\gamma \Delta}{2} [ (a+\frac{\Delta}{2})^{\gamma-1} + b^{\gamma-1}]$.

Comment: I am not sure how I follow from the first inequality how that term becomes an upper bound. Nonetheless, this seems to me to be the kind of bound I am looking for! Do you mind to elaborate a little bit in the steps?

Comment: The bounds I gave are lower bounds of the LHS. Just take the smallest value of the integrands, multiply with the width.